# webSocket doesn't work after deploying to heroku

Tags: heroku, next.js, websocket, ws

I have a nextjs app that must use a webSocket in order to dynamically receive messages from the server that do some complex logic, and the user should see what's going on there.
Everything works on a localhost, but when I deploy it to heroku ( vercel doesn't support such things right? ), well it doesn't work neither...

here's the api route code

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';

type Data = {
    name: string;
};

console.log('the line before creating the WSS');
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 3001 });
console.log('the line after creating the WSS');

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws: any) {
    console.log('Client connected');
    ws.on('close', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));

    ws.on('error', console.error);

    ws.on('message', async function message(data: any) {
        const msg = data.toString();

        switch (msg) {
            case 'all':
                // simulates tasks processing
                ws.send('starting the route');
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
                ws.send('Task1 bridge to arbitrum blabla');
                ws.send('sending transaction...');
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 4000));
                ws.send('sending transaction...');
                ws.send('Transaction completed');
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000));
                ws.send('Task completed');
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));
                ws.send('Task2: swap ETH TO USDC on UniSwap');

                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 4000));
                ws.send('sending transaction...');
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000));
                ws.send('Transaction completed');
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 6000));
                ws.send('Task completed');
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 8000));
                ws.send('Route completed, congratulations soon you will be from the bahata simya');

            default:
                break;
        }
    });
});

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Data>) {
    // if (req.method !== 'GET' && req.method !== 'POST') {
    // }
    res.status(200);
}
```

and here's the client side code

```
const startTheWsServer = async () => {
    const res = await (await fetch('/api/go', { method: 'GET' })).json();
    console.log(res);

    setWSSStarted(true);
};
useEffect(() => {
    startTheWsServer();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    socket = new WebSocket('wss://doubletop.herokuapp.com:3001');
    // socket.addEventListener('open', (event: any) => {
    //  if (socket.state === 1) socket.send('Hello Server!');
    // });

    // Listen for messages
    socket.addEventListener('message', (event: any) => {
        console.log('Message from server');

        setProgressInfo(prevState => {
            if (prevState?.length) {
                return [...prevState, event.data];
            } else {
                return [event.data];
            }
        });
    });

    return () => {
        if (socket.readyState === 1) socket.close();
    };
}, [wssStarted]);
```

the url of the client's websocket is the url heroku gave after deploying. Should it be the one? So when I deploy, I see thise cosole log lines 'the line before creating the WSS' and 'after', so the wss probably is getting initialized, the ws client is trying to connect when I press 'go do smth' and it says hold on I'm still in the connecting state, and after some time it throws an error that it couldn't connect and after some time another one that the state is now closing or already closed....
Yes, I googled the article on a logrocket or smth with sockets.io and that method gives even more errors... So please explain how to implement webSocket connectction correctly on heroku inside of a nextjs app. Thank you.